# Orphaned Postmeta Records in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post-meta, orphan

This may sound like a ridiculous question, but I've seen a lot of weird stuff from WordPress plugins...

I have about 105K orphan records in the postmeta table. As a general rule, can I assume that all orphaned records can be deleted? I have this sneaking suspicion that some plugins park their data in postmeta records w/o a corresponding post record...

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like most records can be deleted - FWIW, I've seen some **very** non-std uses of postmeta in WP.